# Why is this simple query making up 50% execution time?

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, join, postgresql-9.5

I'm using postgresql 9.5. I installed the `pg_stat_statements` extension to analyze queries and got the following surprising result:

```
scheduler=# SELECT substring(query, 1, 30) AS query,                                                                                                                              calls,                                                                                                                                                                      round(total_time::numeric, 2) AS total_time,                                                                                                                                round(mean_time::numeric, 2) AS mean_time,
      round((100 * total_time / sum(total_time) OVER ())::numeric, 2) AS percentage
FROM pg_stat_statements
ORDER BY total_time DESC
LIMIT 10;
             query              | calls | total_time  | mean_time | percentage
--------------------------------+-------+-------------+-----------+------------
 SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth | 41468 | 14663721.55 |    353.62 |      50.84
 SELECT "rsvp_event"."id", "rsv | 24052 |  1405270.05 |     58.43 |       4.87
 SELECT "scheduler_playofffixtu |  1722 |  1282956.76 |    745.04 |       4.45
 SELECT "teammgr_team"."id", "t |  1651 |   943087.30 |    571.22 |       3.27
 SELECT "scheduler_match"."id", |  2206 |   828515.56 |    375.57 |       2.87
 SELECT "scheduler_match"."star |  1455 |   745773.01 |    512.56 |       2.59
 SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth |  2085 |   526799.42 |    252.66 |       1.83
 SELECT "scheduler_match"."id", |   781 |   482996.54 |    618.43 |       1.67
 SELECT (?) AS "a" FROM "schedu |  3389 |   471169.19 |    139.03 |       1.63
 SELECT "scheduler_playofffixtu |   641 |   470971.65 |    734.75 |       1.63
```

The query in question is:

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id", 
       "auth_user"."password", 
       "auth_user"."last_login", 
       "auth_user"."is_superuser", 
       "auth_user"."username", 
       "auth_user"."first_name", 
       "auth_user"."last_name", 
       "auth_user"."email", 
       "auth_user"."is_staff", 
       "auth_user"."is_active", 
       "auth_user"."date_joined" 
FROM "auth_user" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "schedule_maker_association_admins" ON ( "auth_user"."id" = "schedule_maker_association_admins"."user_id" ) 
WHERE ("auth_user"."is_staff" = ? 
       OR "schedule_maker_association_admins"."association_id" = ?)
```

It checks whether a user is staff or the admin of a given association. This is a very common query in our app.

I am not a db expert but I don't see anything wrong with it. The involved columns are indexes:

```
scheduler=# \d schedule_maker_association_admins
                             Table "public.schedule_maker_association_admins"
     Column     |  Type   |                                   Modifiers
----------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer | not null default nextval('schedule_maker_association_admins_id_seq'::regclass)
 association_id | integer | not null
 user_id        | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "schedule_maker_association_admins_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "schedule_maker_association__association_id_4724c38a38e0bdb_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (association_id, user_id)
    "schedule_maker_association_admins_association_id" btree (association_id)
    "schedule_maker_association_admins_user_id" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "association_id_refs_id_6974cbf10541a1a3" FOREIGN KEY (association_id) REFERENCES schedule_maker_association(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "user_id_refs_id_4b393f8cdfbf03cc" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

And here's `auth_user`:

```
Indexes:
    "auth_user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "auth_user_username_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (username)
```

I've analyzed it and found nothing suspcious, but it does take 300-400 ms. I would expect such simple query to be much faster.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "schedule_maker_association_admins" ON ( "auth_user"."id" = "schedule_maker_association_admins"."user_id" ) WHERE ("auth_user"."is_staff" = true OR "schedule_maker_association_admins"."association_id" = 123456);



Merge Left Join  (cost=0.84..59074.80 rows=2 width=174) (actual time=0.012..308.119 rows=15 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (auth_user.id = schedule_maker_association_admins.user_id)
   Filter: (auth_user.is_staff OR (schedule_maker_association_admins.association_id = 123456))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 439229
   ->  Index Scan using auth_user_pkey on auth_user  (cost=0.42..47174.48 rows=419703 width=174) (actual time=0.005..135.908 rows=425904 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using schedule_maker_association_admins_user_id on schedule_maker_association_admins  (cost=0.42..7426.66 rows=228294 width=8) (actual time=0.004..46.421 rows=227838 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.168 ms
 Execution time: 308.140 ms
(8 rows)
```

Possible explanation and solution?

Edit: here's `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=0.84..59074.80 rows=2 width=174) (actual time=0.009..406.478 rows=15 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (auth_user.id = schedule_maker_association_admins.user_id)
   Filter: (auth_user.is_staff OR (schedule_maker_association_admins.association_id = 123456))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 439231
   Buffers: shared hit=147747
   ->  Index Scan using auth_user_pkey on auth_user  (cost=0.42..47174.48 rows=419703 width=174) (actual time=0.004..217.342 rows=425906 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=116728
   ->  Index Scan using schedule_maker_association_admins_user_id on schedule_maker_association_admins  (cost=0.42..7426.66 rows=228294 width=8) (actual time=0.003..57.262 rows=227840 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=31019
 Planning time: 0.947 ms
 Execution time: 406.536 ms
```

Comment: You probably want to `explain (analyze, buffers)`. You also probably want to upgrade from Postgres 9.5.

Comment: @mustaccio I've added the results for `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` in my question. We will be upgrading our entire software soon, but it may very well not be a version issue.

Comment: No, of course it's not a version issue. If it's an issue at all (with .3 second response time I'd argue it is far from that), it's caused by the lack of useful indexes. You're scanning ~650K index entries, then ~650K table rows, to the total of ~300K pages; to your advantage they are all in memory.

Comment: @mustaccio you're suggesting the indexes I have are not useful?

Comment: For this particular query? not very much, obviously, given "Rows Removed by Filter: 439231". I'd suggest `on auth_user (id, is_staff)` and `on schedule_maker_association_admins (association_id, user_id)`.

Comment: "It checks whether a user is staff or the admin of a given association"  No, it lists all users who meet those criteria.  It doesn't check if one specific user does.  Those are quite different tasks.

Comment: @mustaccio Rows might be included based on either branch of the OR, without satisfying the other branch.  So no index can be very effective there.

Comment: @jjanes true but they _might_ eliminate the need to scan the tables to filter on the condition; the proof is in the pudding of course, clearly.

Comment: You’re missing a filter for it to look at the user you are checking, I’d guess you are doing that check in the app side which is not a good idea. Include your user filter and you shouldn’t need to expand the OR condition (which requires the outer join to complete before it can do anything currently - adding an extra filter which always applies will reduce the work of the join)

Comment: @jjanes the query is generated by Django's ORM. This is the statement: `user.is_staff or association.admins.filter(id=user.id).exists()`. According to their docs, the `.exists()` method should just check for existance, not list all of them.

Comment: @dabadaba  Even if it did just check for existence in schedule_maker_association_admins (it doesn't, but even if it did...), it would still be listing every auth_user which has that property, not checking whether one prespecified auth_user has it.

Answer (score 2):

With the right indexes (you haven't told us what indexes the other table has) you could get this to be efficient by writing the query this way:

```
SELECT whatever FROM "auth_user" where "auth_user"."is_staff" = true 
  UNION 
SELECT whatever FROM "auth_user" 
JOIN "schedule_maker_association_admins" ON ( "auth_user"."id" = "schedule_maker_association_admins"."user_id" ) 
WHERE ("schedule_maker_association_admins"."association_id" = 79)
```

But you will have to think carefully about whether you want UNION, or UNION ALL, or something which differs from both of those.

If someone is both staff and the admin of the given association, should they be returned once or more than once, or doesn't it matter?  If they are staff and also admin of several different associations (none of which are the one you queries for), how many times should they be returned? Does it matter, as long as it is at least once?

Comment: Hi, could you follow up with the help please? Answering your questions: we only care that the user is either staff or admin of the given association. As of the indexes, I updated my question with the indexes of the other table `auth_user`.

Comment: Also I'm not sure your query is doing what is intended. It is selecting *any* staff user in thed database. We don't want that. What we want is to determine whether the given user is staff or is the admin of the given association. The parameters are the user id and the association id.

Comment: @dabadaba Of course it returns any staff.  That is what your original query does as well.  The point was to make it faster, not change its output.  Is_staff is clearly a Boolean, so parameterizing it doesn't make much sense, but that is what you show.